# Coolprop in Python: AttributeError for CP.REFPROP_BACKEND

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code that will allow me to solve a refrigeration cycle using different fluids, however I am getting errors.

```
import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP

# System parameters
Tamb = 273.15 + 85  # Cooling tower design temperature (K)
Tevaporator = 0 + 273.15  # Desired evaporator temperature (K)
Cooling_capacity = 200  # Tons of refrigeration (converted to kW)
Unit_volume = 300000  # ft^3 (converted to m^3)
Compressor_efficiency = 0.75  # Compressor efficiency

# Conversion factors
ft3_to_m3 = 0.0283168
ton_to_kW = 3.5168528

# Calculate cooling capacity in kW
Cooling_capacity_kW = Cooling_capacity * ton_to_kW

def refrigeration_cycle(refrigerant):
  """
  This function calculates basic refrigeration cycle parameters for a given fluid.

  Args:
      refrigerant: String representing the refrigerant type (e.g., 'R717')

  Returns:
      A dictionary containing calculated parameters (COP, compressor work, condenser heat rejection)
  """
  # Set CoolProp backend (update to the correct attribute name)
  CP.set_config_string(CP.REFPROP_BACKEND, 'HEOS')

  # Access refrigerant properties
  try:
      Psat_evap = CP.PropsSI('P', 'T', Tevaporator, 'Q', 1, refrigerant)
      h_evap = CP.PropsSI('H', 'T', Tevaporator, 'P', Psat_evap, refrigerant)
      Psat_cond = CP.PropsSI('P', 'T', Tamb, 'Q', 1, refrigerant)
      h_cond = CP.PropsSI('H', 'T', Tamb, 'P', Psat_cond, refrigerant)
  except:
      print(f"Error retrieving properties for {refrigerant}")
      return None

  # Calculate mass flow rate for the unit
  mass_flow_rate = Cooling_capacity_kW / (h_cond - h_evap)

  # Ideal compressor work
  h_comp_out_s = h_evap + (h_cond - h_evap) / Carnot_COP(Tevaporator, Tamb)

  # Actual compressor work (assuming constant efficiency)
  h_comp_out = h_evap + (h_cond - h_evap) / Compressor_efficiency

  # Calculate heat rejection at condenser for the unit
  condenser_heat_rejection = mass_flow_rate * (h_cond - h_comp_out)

  # Calculate COP
  COP = Cooling_capacity_kW / (h_comp_out - h_evap)

  # Return results as a dictionary
  return {
      'refrigerant': refrigerant,
      'COP': COP,
      'mass_flow_rate': mass_flow_rate,  # kg/s
      'compressor_work': h_comp_out - h_evap,  # kJ/kg
      'condenser_heat_rejection': condenser_heat_rejection  # kW
  }

def Carnot_COP(T_cold, T_hot):
  """
  This function calculates the Carnot COP for a given cold and hot reservoir temperature.

  Args:
      T_cold: Cold reservoir temperature (K)
      T_hot: Hot reservoir temperature (K)

  Returns:
      Carnot COP
  """
  return T_cold / (T_hot - T_cold)

# Define candidate refrigerants
refrigerants = ['R717', 'R410a', 'R404a']

# Run calculations for each refrigerant
for refrigerant in refrigerants:
  cycle_data = refrigeration_cycle(refrigerant)
  if cycle_data:
    # Convert volume to m^3 for mass flow rate calculation
    unit_volume_m3 = Unit_volume * ft3_to_m3
    # Adjust mass flow rate to account for a single unit
    cycle_data['mass_flow_rate'] = cycle_data['mass_flow_rate'] / unit_volume_m3

    # Print results for the single unit
    print(f"Refrigerant: {cycle_data['refrigerant']}")
    print(f"\tCOP: {cycle_data['COP']:.2f}"
```

I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3b7586c7395d> in <cell line: 83>()
     82 # Run calculations for each refrigerant
     83 for refrigerant in refrigerants:
---> 84   cycle_data = refrigeration_cycle(refrigerant)
     85   if cycle_data:
     86     # Convert volume to m^3 for mass flow rate calculation

<ipython-input-2-3b7586c7395d> in refrigeration_cycle(refrigerant)
     28   """
     29   # Set CoolProp backend (update to the correct attribute name)
---> 30   CP.set_config_string(CP.REFPROP_BACKEND, 'HEOS')
     31 
     32   # Access refrigerant properties

AttributeError: module 'CoolProp.CoolProp' has no attribute 'REFPROP_BACKEND'
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that the code on line 30 is wrong; there is no property named `REFPROP_BACKEND`. You should consult the CoolProp documentation for the acceptable values.